# RxJs: Implementing Chatbot delayed messages

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working on chat application where i need to display bot messages one-by-one with some delay between them, such that it gives an impression that bot is typing instead of throwing all message together. I was trying this behaviour with RxJS but could not achieve the desired output.

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fejxom?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts)

```
query(): Observable<IChatResponse> {
    const response = {
      messages: [
        {
          text: 'Please give a valid domain name',
        },
        {
          text: 'What domain do you want?',
        },
        {
          text: 'Some other messages...',
        },
      ],
    };

    return of(response).pipe(
      switchMap((response: any) => this.convertToStream(response))
    );
  }

  convertToStream(data: any): Observable<IChatResponse> {
    let count = 0;
    const messageDelayFn = (sme, idx): Observable<any> => {
      const loaderStart$ = of(null).pipe(
        tap((_) => console.log('idx ', idx)),
        delay(500 * idx),
        tap((_) => {
          this.loading$.next(true);
        })
      );
      const loaderStop$ = of(null).pipe(
        delay(1000 * idx),
        tap((_) => {
          this.loading$.next(false);
        })
      );

      const message$ = of(sme);
      return concat(loaderStart$, loaderStop$, message$).pipe(share());
    };

    const transformedObservable = of(data).pipe(
      map((chat) => {
        return {
          ...chat,
          messages: chat.messages.reduce((acc: Observable<any>[], message) => {
            return [...acc, messageDelayFn(message, ++count)];
          }, []),
        };
      })
    );

    return transformedObservable;
  }
```

Behaviour i am expecting is something like this --,

- starts with loader for 500ms
- loader stops
- emits first message
- again loader starts for 500ms (before emitting second message)
- loader stops
- emits second message
- ...and so on

Comment: And what's your problem with what you have ?

Comment: I am not getting expected output. Loader is visible for first time and then vanishes..but it should show before rendering each message and then go away..Based on loader, i want to let user know that bot is currently typing the message.

Comment: like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gugaxm

Comment: @EddyLin thanks for your response..sorry but I am looking for different behaviour. I want to show loader before emitting each message..as mentioned in above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can greatly simplify your code if you think about your "state" in a different way.  Instead of managing the "loading" and the "messages" separately, we can think about them as part of a single interface:

```js
export interface ChatBotState {
  messages: string[];
  isTyping: boolean;
}
```

Let's create an observable that emits this state the way you want.

We'll first start with your query to get all the messages and emit them one at a time, so we have a stream of individual messages:

```js
  private chatBotMessage$ = this.appService.query().pipe(
    switchMap(response => response.messages)
  );
```

Then we can use [`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) / [`of`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of) to emit the different ChatBotStates with your desired timings:

```js
  public state$: Observable<ChatBotState> = this.chatBotMessage$.pipe(
    concatMap(message => concat(
      of({ isTyping: true,  message: undefined    }).pipe(delay(0)),
      of({ isTyping: false, message: message.text }).pipe(delay(500)),
    )),
    // ... more to come
```

Here we immediately emit a state with `isTyping = true`, then after `500ms` we emit a state with the message text and `isTyping = false`.

We can use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to emit a resultant state object that contains all messages:

```js
const INITIAL_STATE: ChatBotState = {
  messages: [],
  isTyping: false,
};
```

```js
  public state$: Observable<ChatBotState> = this.chatBotMessage$.pipe(
    concatMap(message => concat(
      of({ isTyping: true,  message: undefined    }).pipe(delay(0)),
      of({ isTyping: false, message: message.text }).pipe(delay(1500)),
    )),
    scan((previous, current) => ({
      isTyping: current.isTyping,
      messages: current.message 
                  ? previous.messages.concat(current.message) 
                  : previous.messages
    }), INITIAL_STATE)
  );
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73585266?devtoolsheight=50&file=src%2Fapp%2Fchat-bot.service.ts&devtoolsheight=50) demo.

---

Since the `state$` observable emits exactly the data the view needs, our component becomes really simple!  No need for managing a subscription, so no need for `ngOnInit` or `ngOnDestroy`. You can use a single `async` pipe in the template to unwrap the view model and that's it!

```js
export class AppComponent {

  vm$ = this.chatBotService.state$;

  constructor(private chatBotService: ChatBotService) { }

}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
  
  <p *ngFor="let message of vm.messages">
    {{ message }}
  </p>

  <div *ngIf="vm.isTyping">
    Loading...
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that matches your spec. You can try running this yourself and then hopefully adapt it to your use case as needed.

```ts
function query(): Observable<string> {
  const response = {
    messages: [
      {
        text: 'Please give a valid domain name',
      },
      {
        text: 'What domain do you want?',
      },
      {
        text: 'Some other messages...',
      },
    ],
  };

  return concat(...response.messages.map(({text}) => 
    timer(500).pipe(map(_ => text))
  ));
}

query().subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

**service**

```
export default class AppService {
  query(): Observable<IMessage> {
    const response = {
      messages: [
        {
          text: 'Please give a valid domain name',
        },
        {
          text: 'What domain do you want?',
        },
        {
          text: 'Some other messages...',
        },
      ],
    };
    return from(response.messages);
  }
}
```

**component**

```
export class AppComponent {
  text$ = this.appService.query().pipe(
    concatMap(({ text }) => {
      const share$ = of(text).pipe(delay(1000), share());
      return share$.pipe(delay(1000), startWith(share$), skipLast(1));
    }),
    scan((arr, v) => [...arr, v], [])
  );
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {}
}
```

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of text$ | async">
  <div class="text">
    <span *ngIf="item | async as item; else loading">
      {{ item }}
    </span>
    <ng-template #loading>
      <img src="https://c.tenor.com/VS20soWAM9AAAAAi/loading.gif" width="30"/>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ot6dcr

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Using subject combined with concat, since concat will execute the next observable only after the previous observable completes, I have added a delay and it seems to work as per the requirements.

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  concat,
  map,
  Observable,
  of,
  share,
  switchMap,
  tap,
  delay,
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject,
  concatMap,
} from 'rxjs';
import { IChatResponse } from './app.component';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export default class AppService {
  loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  get loadingStream(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loading$.asObservable();
  }

  query(): Observable<any> {
    const subject = new BehaviorSubject(['loading']);
    const response = {
      messages: [
        {
          text: 'Please give a valid domain name',
        },
        {
          text: 'What domain do you want?',
        },
        {
          text: 'Some other messages...',
        },
      ],
    };
    const observables$ = response.messages.map((x) => {
      return of(x.text).pipe(delay(3000));
    });

    return concat(...observables$).pipe(
      tap((x) => {
        const arr = subject.getValue();
        arr[arr.length - 1] = x;
        subject.next(
          arr.length === response.messages.length ? arr : [...arr, 'loading']
        );
      }),
      concatMap(() => subject.asObservable())
    );
  }
}
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import AppService from './app.service';

export interface IChatResponse {
  messages: Observable<IMessage>[];
}
interface IMessage {
  text: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  chatMessages$: any;
  subscription = new Subscription();
  loader$: Observable<boolean>;
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.loader$ = this.appService.loadingStream;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.chatMessages$ = <any>this.appService.query();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p *ngFor="let message of chatMessages$ | async">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="message">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'loading'">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        style="margin:auto;background:#fff;display:block;"
        width="200px"
        height="200px"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      >
        <g transform="translate(20 50)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#e15b64">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="scale"
              begin="-0.375s"
              calcMode="spline"
              keySplines="0.3 0 0.7 1;0.3 0 0.7 1"
              values="0;1;0"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              dur="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            ></animateTransform>
          </circle>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(40 50)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#f8b26a">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="scale"
              begin="-0.25s"
              calcMode="spline"
              keySplines="0.3 0 0.7 1;0.3 0 0.7 1"
              values="0;1;0"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              dur="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            ></animateTransform>
          </circle>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(60 50)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#abbd81">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="scale"
              begin="-0.125s"
              calcMode="spline"
              keySplines="0.3 0 0.7 1;0.3 0 0.7 1"
              values="0;1;0"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              dur="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            ></animateTransform>
          </circle>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(80 50)">
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="#81a3bd">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="scale"
              begin="0s"
              calcMode="spline"
              keySplines="0.3 0 0.7 1;0.3 0 0.7 1"
              values="0;1;0"
              keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
              dur="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            ></animateTransform>
          </circle>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>{{ message }}</ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</p>
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-udcckf)

Comment: @Ricky please check now, made a mistake!

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but i can't add loader text as part of message stream. I want different loader stream and message stream.

Something like this -- 
https://hellotars.com/blog/chatbot-message-delays

Comment: as mentioned above, I cannot add "loading" text with all other messages. I want different observable for messages and different observable for loader. Also, in your solution, loader is always shown until all messages are delivered. My expectation is different. There is one point where i want to hide the loader just before emitting the message.